# Slot Machine Issues while testing

Tags: java

I’m getting a few things in the output of my slot machine program that aren’t quite correct. Here’s the output that I’m getting:

```
Want to test your luck?
To Spin, type any positive number
To End Game, type -1 and press enter 
2
21
0
We have twins... You've matched a pair!
Want to test your luck?
To Spin, type any positive number
To End Game, type -1 and press enter
```

The first three lines are what displays when you first run the program. In this case I typed in a number 2 to start.

- One issue I’m having is that the input to start the game is being counted as one of the numbers for slots.
- The second issue I’m having is out of the 3 numbers for each slot I am getting numbers larger than 9, which I don’t see how when I specified to be between 0-9.
- Last but not least the final error I’m getting in my code is that the line after the numbers I have set to say “We have twins… You’ve matched a pair!” Although there is no pair? Unless it is just counting the two’s.

Here is my complete program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Java_Lab_3 {
    private static int endgame = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int slot1;
        int slot2;
        int slot3;
        int count1 = 0;
        Random rand =  new Random();
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);  

        while (endgame != -1) {
            System.out.println("Want to test your luck?");
            System.out.println("To Spin, type any positive number");
            System.out.println("To End Game, type -1 and press enter ");

           endgame = keyboard.nextInt();

            slot1 = rand.nextInt(10);
            slot2 = rand.nextInt(10);
            slot3 = rand.nextInt(10);

            System.out.println(slot1 + slot2 + slot3);
            System.out.println(count1); 

            if (slot1 == slot2 && slot1 == slot3) { // Then they have JACKPOT
                System.out.println("You've Won!");
            } else if (slot1 == slot2 || slot2 == slot3 || slot1 == slot3) { // 
    They MATCHED 2
               System.out.println("We have twins... You've matched a pair!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sucks to Suck, don't quit your day job!");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program works fine. Just change

```
System.out.println(slot1 + slot2 + slot3);
```

to

```
System.out.println(slot1 + " " + slot2 + " " + slot3);
```

to perform string concatenation rather than addition so you can see the actual values of your slots rather than their sum.